# How can i add mobile camera feed to unity?

Tags: unity, augmented-reality

I want to take my mobile camera's feed to unity , where if the target image is found , some action should happen ( may be like a cuboid appears on the target image). I thought of using ip webcam app which generates ip address , through browser i was able to see the camera feed. I want the feed from camera but the action must be in my laptop.

Comment: Presumably you read through the [documentation on using Unity's Vuforia integration](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/vuforia-sdk-overview.html) to accomplish this image recognition and tracking? What have you tried based on your research so far, and where have you run into a blocker you need help with?